# Реализовать группировку, суммирование и вычитание таблиц в запросе SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных

В БД есть 3 таблицы. Нужно сделать запрос, что бы из просуммированного поля QUANTITY первой таблицы вычесть просуммированные поля с этим же кодом товара второй и третьей таблицы.
GOOD - код товара

```
SELECT dst.GOOD, SUM(QUANTITY) FROM DOC_SESSION_TABLE dst 
WHERE GOOD=12300
GROUP BY GOOD
```

(данный запрос выдает: 12300 | 150)

```
SELECT dst2.GOOD, SUM(QUANTITY) FROM DOC_SALE_TABLE dst2
WHERE GOOD=12300
GROUP BY GOOD
```

(данный запрос выдает: 12300 | 100)

```
SELECT dbt.GOOD, SUM(QUANTITY) FROM DOC_BALANCE_TABLE dbt
WHERE GOOD=12300
GROUP BY GOOD
```

(данный запрос выдает: 12300 | 5)

Необходимый запрос должен вывести: 12300 | 45

Comment: делаете один запрос, который делает select from из union из 3 select GOOD, QUANTITY, в одном из которых QUANTITY как есть, а в двух других `-QUANTITY`, ну а дальше суммируете и группируете все как сейчас

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это то, о чём говорит @Mike

```
SELECT SQ.GOOD, SUM(SQ.QUANTITY) FROM
(
    SELECT dst.GOOD, dst.QUANTITY FROM DOC_SESSION_TABLE dst WHERE dst.GOOD=12300
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dst2.GOOD, -dst2.QUANTITY FROM DOC_SALE_TABLE dst2 WHERE dst2.GOOD=12300
    UNION ALL
    SELECT dbt.GOOD, -dbt.QUANTITY FROM DOC_BALANCE_TABLE dbt WHERE dbt.GOOD=12300
) SQ
GROUP BY SQ.GOOD
```